# csh: Terminal inherits environment variables from an unknown location

Tags: shell, terminal, environment-variables, csh

I'm on a shared machine running `CentOS 5.10` that I log onto using VNC from Windows 7. Our default and official shell is `csh`.

Every time I open a new terminal, I have three particular environment variables (related to the [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) system) that are mysteriously set somewhere.

I can't find them in `.cshrc`, nor in `.login` (which I don't have anyway), nor in `/etc/csh.cshrc` or `/etc/csh.login` or anywhere else I can think of.

Is there a way to trace what sources them?

Just to clarify, if I log onto the gateway machine using PuTTY, I don't face that issue.

Comment: Perhaps from `/etc/profile.d/*.csh`? These files are usually sourced by `/etc/csh.cshrc`. And did you check `~/.tcshrc`? Most `csh` shells these days are really `tcsh`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No, couldn't find them there, they are all called MODULEPATH or something so `grep`ing for MODULE didn't yield anything, unfortunately.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html), `MODULEPATH` can be edited with `module use [-a|--append] directory` (or is it `modulecmd use ...`?  I can't seem to parse that page).

Comment: @lcd047 The issue is that those environment variables are set even before my shell sources `.cshrc`, I print it at the top of the file right before anything else and it's already there. However on PuTTY, that's not the case (it comes up as undefined). What could the terminal be inheriting the environment from? Some kind of parent process?

Comment: Have you considered asking your sysadmin?

Comment: I have, but typically they were very busy and only had a cursory look and accused me of sourcing scripts that set them and/or couldn't investigate properly. I was hoping to resolve this on my own or at least be pointed to something specific I could ask them to do (like maybe restarting a certain parent process that could be responsible). I will badger them on Monday again if this is still the case.

Comment: You can always try `grep -r MODULEPATH /` or some such ...

Comment: In the end I logged out and logged back in again as per our sysadmin's recommendation (I've provided an explanation as to why in an answer).

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with my system administrator and he suggested that the terminal session somehow inherits the environment variable from the current login process/session(?) and recommended I completely log out and log back in again (which I desperately wanted to avoid doing as I have a lot of important terminal sessions in various workspaces I didn't want to waste time restoring).

His explanation for why I didn't face that problem with PuTTY was due to PuTTY initiating a new login session.

It fixed my problem but sadly I couldn't get to the root cause of where that environment variable had come from.