# gnome-terminal inherits some environment even with 'env -i' on a vnc session

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, gnome-terminal, x11vnc

Some how, gnome-terminal able to get some environment which are not set in any of shell init files(sytem-wide/user-level)

```
env -i DISPLAY=":1.0" /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

`$> env` gives many other variables, where as xterm only give a few as below

```
env -i DISPLAY=":1.0" /usr/bin/xterm
$> env
DISPLAY=:1.0
TERM=xterm
WINDOWID=37748770
XTERM_VERSION=X.Org 6.8.99.903(253)
XTERM_LOCALE=C
LOGNAME=bkatkam
XTERM_SHELL=/bin/csh
HOSTTYPE=x86_64-linux
VENDOR=unknown
OSTYPE=linux
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/bkatkam
USER=bkatkam
GROUP=inv
HOST=inv2
```

But, These are getting cleared in new VNC session. I suspect, vnc session is storing environment somewhere. I couldn't able to figure out where it has stored them.

I have also went through, [csh: Terminal inherits environment variables from an unknown location](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202218/csh-terminal-inherits-environment-variables-from-an-unknown-location),
But root cause was not found in this question.

Edit:
`env -i` command is now giving proper environment, after closing all open gnome-terminals. 
But still if I open terminal normally(without `env -i`), unrelated environment are getting inherited

Comment: Does `gone-terminal` start a login shell by default? In that case, it may read system-wide shell initialization files. The shell may still read system-wide init files if it's an interactive shell, too.

Comment: @Kusalananda, It's an interactive shell. Am sure, they were not set in system-wide init files like `/etc/csh.cshrc`. I have edited `/etc/csh.cshrc` to have `env; exit` on first line, even then these unrelated environments are coming up. Also, these are not coming with new vnc session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging, got to know that
`gnome-terminal` inherits environment from it's parent `Xvnc` process

`Xvnc` in-turn gets environment from terminal on which `vncserver` was executed to create VNC.
So, to ensure VNC with clean environment. I have created it with command

```
env -i PATH="/usr/bin:/bin" HOME="/home/bkatkam" vncserver -geometry 1920x1080
```